# Eloquent Model static methods with composition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, casting, composition

I have an ClientInvoice object that has an Eloquent model field that holds the underlying transaction object:

```
class Invoice
{
    /**
     * Object Model
     *
     * @var Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */

    private $model; 

    public function __construct(){
        $this->model = new Transaction();
        $this->model->transaction_type = "Invoice";
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is have access to the model static database management functions such as find like:

```
Invoice::find(int $id) : Invoice; // where id is the underlying Transaction Object Id
```

Essentially the problem is, is it possible to cast the result of Transaction::find(int $id) to the overlying Invoice type without calling its constructor?

Comment: That should be doable with PHPs magic function [`__callStatic`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic).

Comment: You are not extending any base class. How about extending `Model` base class?

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Invoice extends Model
{

Comment: @HameesA.Khan Transaction extends the Model Bas class. I'm trying to follow the [Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) design pattern as there are many types of transactions such as Invoices and Bills, but all have an underlying Transaction object